# Word VBA Macro for highlighting same style with 5 different colors

Tags: vba, colors, ms-word, highlight

I need to make a Macro to find all the ocurrances of a specific style (they are all titles which share the same style) and highlight then in 5 different colors sequentally.  I already have a code to do this once, but I need to repeat this to the end of the document.  I understand the code is very crude, so if anyone can help me make it shorter, and more efficiente i would appreciate also.

```
Sub Highlight()
'
' highlight Macro
'
'
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Rashi Char")
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.Highlight = True
With Selection.Find
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindAsk
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchKashida = False
    .MatchDiacritics = False
    .MatchAlefHamza = False
    .MatchControl = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Rashi Char")
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.Highlight = True
With Selection.Find
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindAsk
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchKashida = False
    .MatchDiacritics = False
    .MatchAlefHamza = False
    .MatchControl = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdTurquoise
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Rashi Char")
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.Highlight = True
With Selection.Find
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindAsk
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchKashida = False
    .MatchDiacritics = False
    .MatchAlefHamza = False
    .MatchControl = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdPink
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Rashi Char")
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.Highlight = True
With Selection.Find
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindAsk
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchKashida = False
    .MatchDiacritics = False
    .MatchAlefHamza = False
    .MatchControl = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdGreen
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Rashi Char")
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.Highlight = True
With Selection.Find
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindAsk
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchKashida = False
    .MatchDiacritics = False
    .MatchAlefHamza = False
    .MatchControl = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches. I'll describe both briefly.

1. Take all the properties that do not change from one iteration to another and group them near the top of the code. You don't need to set these things each time, once is enough. I'm talking about almost everything inside the With `Selection.Find ... End With` construct. You can then delete the repeated code that you don't need. That will shorten your code quite a bit.

When you use the Selection object, the settings you make affect the Find dialog box. So they persist until you (or other code) changes them. That's why this should work for you.

2. The other approach is to place the code that repeats in its own procedure. Call the procedure for each iteration you want to have. In order to change certain characteristics, define one or more parameters and pass that information.

For example, you could pass the style name for which you search and the highlight color. The method signature would be something like:

```
Sub FindAndHighlight(TextToFind as String, HighlightColor as Long)
```

And you'd call it like this:

```
FindAndHighlight "Rashi Char", wdGreen
```

This will help shorten your code (and make it easier to read) because it puts all the actions that repeat in one place, so you only have to write it once.

Answer (score 0):

What you wan to use is a `Do While`, see script below.

```
Sub Highlight()
'
' highlight Macro
'
'
'Going to the top of the Document
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

'Setting up your Selection.Find
With Selection.find
    .text = ""
    .Replacement.text = ""
    .style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Rashi Char")
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindAsk
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchKashida = False
    .MatchDiacritics = False
    .MatchAlefHamza = False
    .MatchControl = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False

    'Setting your counter for selecting which colour for highlighting
    d = 1

    'Executing the search
    Do While .Execute

        'If d = 1 then its 1 of 5
        If d = 1 Then
            Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
        'If d = 2 then its 2 of 5
        ElseIf d = 2 Then
            Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
        'If d = 3 then its 3 of 5
        ElseIf d = 3 Then
            Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdTurquoise
        'If d = 4 then its 4 of 5
        ElseIf d = 4 Then
            Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdPink
        'If d = 5 then its 5 of 5
        ElseIf d = 5 Then
            Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdGreen
        End If
        'Incrementing d
        d = d + 1
        'If d = 6 then you have completed the highlighting loop
        'Then set d back to 1
        If d = 6 Then d = 1

     Loop
'Ending the Selectin.Find With
End With

End Sub
```

I have tested it with using `Header 1` as my `.style` and it worked perfectly.